Invalid initializer error with anonymous structs
I have this code here:
Void() aba ()
{
}
#define std_Dynamic_Array(T) struct{Int32() count; Int32() capacity; T* memory; }
Void() no_body_func (Int32() b);
Int32() test_func (Int32()*** a)
{
}
Int32() test_func2 (Int32() x)
{
}
Int32() b = 33;
#define v_macro(T) struct{Int32() count; Int32() capacity; T* memory; } v (std_Dynamic_Array(T)* m) \
{ \
    Int32() l = 44; \
}
Void() _main ()
{
    Int64() a = 5;
    b = 22;
    Int32() c = test_func2(6);
    Int32() inner_func (Int32()* a)
    {
        Int32() g = 3;
    }
    Int32()* x = &b;
    inner_func(x);
    Int32() j = *x;
    Float32() f = 33.000000;
    std_Dynamic_Array(Int64()) da = {.count = 4};
    v_macro(Int64());
    std_Dynamic_Array(Int64()) k = v(&da);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    return 0;
}


I'm playing around with writing my own compiler that can generate C code as one of the targets. My problem is that I'm getting this weird error:
tests/simple.c:34:36: error: invalid initializer
   34 |     std_Dynamic_Array(Int64()) k = v(&da);
      |                                    ^

Here's code generated by gcc -E ...
void aba ()
{
}

void no_body_func (int b);
int test_func (int*** a)
{
}
int test_func2 (int x)
{
}
int b = 33;




void _main ()
{
    long long a = 5;
    b = 22;
    int c = test_func2(6);
    int inner_func (int* a)
    {
        int g = 3;
    }
    int* x = &b;
    inner_func(x);
    int j = *x;
    float f = 33.000000;
    struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; } da = {.count = 4};
    struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; } v (struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; }* m) { int l = 44; };
    struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; } k = v(&da);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    return 0;
}

Why is this error happening? Both v's return type and k's type expand to struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; } , so why does GCC treat them as different types?
What can I possibly do to fix this?
Also:

I don't care about code readability, this is generated code meant for GCC, not for humans to deal with.
If the solution requires the most hacky GCC trickery known to man and language extensions, so be it. The C target outputs code that will work strictly with GCC, no need to worry about clang, MSVC, ICC, etc.

I know I could probably solve this by generating some typedefs, but I want to avoid that. For now at least.
Thanks!!

Where did you get that awful code from? What is the purpose of that code? Are there no header files included which defines things like Void() or Int32()? Not to mention that nested functions are not part of C. There are just so many things wrong with both the original and the preprocessed code.

"so why does GCC treat them as different types": They are different types. Two structures without tags can only be compatible if they are declared in different translation units.

And regarding "this is generated code"... If that's true then there's something seriously wrong with the program that generated that awful code. A code-generator that creates invalid code is of no use.

"If the solution requires the most hacky GCC trickery known to man and language extensions, so be it.": I haven't tested it, but with -fpermissive GCC tolerates a lot of things...

this is generated code meant for GCC, not for humans to deal with Yet here you are....

@Someprogrammerdude There's always a use for bad examples. ;-)

@Someprogrammerdude The awful code is the generated C code from my compiler. There's no real purpose to that code, it's just output from a simple test file written in my language. This is NOT a part of my compiler, it's what it has generated. I'm sorry if this wasn't obvious from my original post, english isn't my first language.

@AndrewHenle I said that, because I don't want the solution to be "pretty". I just want to be able to compile the generated code. I just don't know what C code should my compiler generate

Then I'm sorry to say that your compiler doesn't generate valid code. C doesn't have nested functions. And functions which are declared to return a value must return a value. You need to make sure the compiler doesn't generate invalid code, no matter the syntax or semantics of the code it's supposed to compile. You need to know a lot about not only the original source language, but also the language generated by the compiler.

@Someprogrammerdude: GCC does have nested functions, and OP said they are targeting strictly GCC. C does have nested functions. The C standard is only one specification of a C language or family of languages, and nobody is required to use it. There is no reason for you to criticize work that is deliberately using a different version of the C language. ISO does not have a monopoly on the C language, and people are free to use other variants.

@Someprogrammerdude GCC extensions do allow for nested functions. Functions don't have to return a value, you'll just get a warning, but I've suppressed all warnings. Also, I'm asking this question, because my compiler doesn't generate "compile-able" code, because of the struct issue. You don't need to tell me that the code is wrong. That's why I'm asking a question

@Someprogrammerdude: Re “And functions which are declared to return a value must return a value”: This is false even in the C standard. int foo(void) {} int main(void) { foo(); } is a valid program with behavior fully specified by the C standard. Further, given these functions are completely empty and OP is clearly tinkering with a transpiler under development, it is likely this is just preliminary placeholder code to be developed further. You should recognize that and not clutter Stack Overflow with misplaced criticism.

Suppressing warnings is a good way to get code that leads to undefined behavior. Yes, a function could skip the return statement, but what happens with the code that calls the function and expects it to return something? Like k = v(&da)... You have declared that the function should return one of your structures, and you want to initialize the variable k with it. But since v doesn't return anything that will lead to undefined behavior, making the whole program wrong.

And is it your teacher (or other learning resource) that taught you to rely on compiler-specific and non-standard extensions? Then that's really not a good teacher or resource. If your compiler generates plain simple standard C, then it can be used by everyone, even those that doesn't have GCC. If I was your teacher, I would have tested your compiler using not only invalid source code, but also with other C compilers. And considering the code it currently generates (which do lead to UB) I would have failed you.

@Someprogrammerdude: Re “And is it your teacher (or other learning resource) that taught you to rely on compiler-specific and non-standard extensions?”: Nonsense. There are plenty of business situations in which it is appropriate and good engineering to rely on compiler-specific and non-standard extensions. There is no universal requirement that everybody use the C standard. To see what utter nonsense this is, consider how much work has gone into GCC and Clang extensions. These extensions exist for the purpose of relying on their features, and there is clearly demand for them.

@Someprogrammerdude This is a hobby project, just having fun over the summer. The entire point is to generate code SPECIFICALLY for GCC. This a very much DESIRED limitation that makes it so I can comfortably rely on language extensions and GCC specific tricks to make things work. That's like generating NASM code and getting angry, because it doesn't work with GAS or some other tool. Move your head a little

@kamkow1: You can ignore Someprogrammerdude. Their comments are off base.

@EricPostpischil better for my sanity

@EricPostpischil int foo(void) {} int main(void) { foo(); } is a valid program with behavior fully specified by the C standard  That's only valid because you've specified the missing return value isn't accessed.  Might as well park a car next to a cliff so that it has to be put in reverse to drive away then giving the car's keys to a blindfolded driver and neglecting to mention the cliff in front of the car...

@AndrewHenle: My comment here is not intended to educate novice users and should not be, as that is not a purpose of comments. It is intended to correct the false statement made by Someprogrammerdude. Their comment was inappropriate in the first place—it’s absurd to come in and criticize intentionally incomplete code as being incomplete. That is just placeholder code for a project in development, and it was not part of the question and should not have been commented on.

Every definition of a structure creates a distinct type, and this is a deliberate and desirable feature of C. If we have:
typedef struct { double a, b; } GeometricPoint;
typedef struct { double a, b; } ComplexNumber;

then we want GeometricPoint and ComplexNumber to be different types so that one cannot be accidentally assigned to the other, even if their layout is identical.
Everywhere in your code that you have struct{int count; int capacity; long long* memory; }, you have a different type, and each of these types is incompatible with the others, and thus you get warnings and errors when trying to assign one to another, to pass one as an argument for another, or to try assignments or argument passing with pointers to them.
To fix this, declare the structure once with a tag:
struct MyStructure { int count; int capacity; long long *memory; };

and then use only struct with the tag, struct MyStructure, throughout the rest of the code. Alternately, you can use a typedef:
typedef struct { int count; int capacity; long long *memory; } MyStructure;

and then use the typedef name, MyStructure, throughout the rest of the code.
